# Redux - initializing a prop in the store with function

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Say had a reducer for a certain state

```
... function thisFunction (
state = new state, 
action
)
{
switch(type) {
     case INIT_STATE:
        return {
          ...state, 
          ...action.state
        }
        default:
          return {
           certainProp: setCertainProp(state.certainProp, action)
        }
```

and my reducer for it

```
function setCertainProp(state = {}, action) {
     const { type } = action
         switch (type) {
             case SET_CERTAIN_PROP:
                 return action.certainProp
             default:
                 return state
```

and now my action

```
function setCertainPropAction(prop){
    return {
        type: SET_CERTAIN_PROP
        action: prop
     }
}
```

now inside my container in a `componentDidMount` or `useEffect` I want `certainProp`'s value to
come from a `fetch` call

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchCertainProp().then(response => setCertainPropAction(response)
}, [])
```

my question is, is it possible to completely remove the useEffect here and call the `fetchCertainProp()` from inside the initialization of `certainProp` within the reducer?
I have access to `redux-thunks` but I haven't seen an example of how this would be possible. I don't want to add an unnecessary `useEffect` if I don't need too.

Comment: If the `fetchCertainProp` function has a side effect, you can't use it inside reducer function. Reducer function should be pure.

Comment: You need to use an async action (like thunk) to get this value into the store, or alternatively fetch the value *before* the redux store itself is created (where the app is bootstrapped usually) - so that the value is already present when the initialState is set.